# Need to uninstall .Net Framework 4.8.1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

My password manager doesn't work with this version and needs a lower one.  It gives the following error when I try to run it:
"To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
v2.0.50727
v4.0"

And ofcourse, having version 4.8.1 prevents me from installing 4.0, although it still has a registry mention.

So now I can't get to my 100s of passwords unless I get 4.8.1 off of my system.
Can anyone help me with this?
Maybe through some registry tampering?
I can't even read my emails any more now!.

Comment: “Can anyone help me with this?” - What you want, to uninstall .NET Framework 4.8.1 is impossible, but what isn’t impossible is to get the software to otherwise work provided you give us enough information to diagnose the actual problem. What software are you trying to run? The only other version of .NET Framework that can be installed on Windows 10 22H2 is .NET Framework 3.5, every other version, is replaced by .NET 4.8.1. The only exception to that statement is .NET Core installations which is not applicable to your problem

Comment: The only way we can help you is if you [edit] your question to include the necessary information to diagnose your problems, what isn’t possible, is removing .NET Framework 4.8.1 that’s only factual undeniable fact.

Comment: Windows 10 is currently supported until 2025. This problem would exist even if the author upgraded to Windows 11. This problem can be solved, trivially so, with a little diagnostic work from the community. Your answer didn’t answer the authors question. Using a different password manager should be the last option the user takes if and only if there isn’t another option

Comment: The first step to diagnosing this problem is providing us KeePass.exe.config if you are indeed using KeePass 2. If you’re using the portable version. You need to make that clear when you edit your question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the data is to revert to an older version of Windows on which it worked.

- Make a disk image of the PC *now*, so you can revert to it.
- If you have an old disk image

  - *Restore the disk image*.
  - Run the pass word manager.
  - Export all passwords as plain text to USB.
  - Restore Windows 10 from image.
- Otherwise, a **slower and less likely to succeed** alternative

  - Download an ISO for the old OS.
  - Install it on USB, e.g. with Hasleo's [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html).
  - Install the password manager.
  - Try to access your old passwords on the main drive.
  - Export them as plain text to USB.